# Advanced filter for a big matrix, how to get all the information for a employee just putting his employee number in

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a big matrix that has all employees in my company (more than 1500) in two different documents (internal and external), I have created a new document that I want to use to have specific information about an employee by just putting in his employee number.

I can get all the specific information like: name, insurrance number, working area, etc. but the problem is when I try to get the courses that he has done (because is more than one result) it has like 10-20 results and I need all the courses to show up instead of just the first one, like when I use the VLOOKUP formula.

---

That table looks like this:

Name   Course    Date    Status

---

Does anyone have an idea if that is possible? thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was explored over at exceljet.net on [this post](https://exceljet.net/formula/get-nth-match-with-index-match).  To avoid link rot:

> Generic formula

```
{=INDEX(array,SMALL(IF(vals=val,ROW(vals)-ROW(INDEX(vals,1,1))+1),nth))}
```

> Explanation
>
> To get the nth match using INDEX and MATCH, you can use an array formula that uses the IF and SMALL functions to figure out the row number of the match.
>
> In the example shown, the formula in I7 is:

```
{=INDEX(amts,SMALL(IF(ids=id,ROW(ids)-ROW(INDEX(ids,1,1))+1),H6))}
```

> Where named ranges are amts (D4:D11), id (I3), and ids (C4:C11).
>
> *Note that this is an array formula and must be entered with **Control + Shift + Enter**.*

I did a little more work and got what's below.  Note that I turned the original data (columns A, B, and C) into "Table1" by using Insert > Table, and the headers are named helpfully.

```
   A           B        C             D       E      F
3                                    looking for:    Bill
4
5  Name      debt     currency       nth    Debts   In...
6  Bill        50      USD             1      50     USD
7  Bill        49      EU              2      49     EU
8  Susan      100      USD             3      51     EU
9  Charles    100      LI              4      30     WON
10 Bill        51      EU              5
11 Bill        30      WON             6
```

...and here's the formulas:

```
debts
=IFERROR(INDEX(Table1[debt],SMALL(IF(Table1[Name]=$F$3,ROW(Table1[Name])-ROW(INDEX(Table1[Name],1,1))+1),$D6)),"")

in...
=IFERROR(INDEX(Table1[Currency],SMALL(IF(Table1[Name]=$F$3,ROW(Table1[Name])-ROW(INDEX(Table1[Name],1,1))+1),$D6)),"")
```

Note that $D6 is intended to increase for each row (i.e. $D7, $D8, etc).

Make sure to finish typing the equation with ctrl-shift-enter in order for the array formulas to work!  You'll know this is working because the curly brackets {} appear.

Comment: Thank you so much!, this helped me a lot!